# commas in conjunction with a prepositional phrase (with...)

Tags: meaning, punctuation, commas, ambiguity

> a. In the photo you see her with Dave standing on a rock.
>
> b. In the photo you see her, with Dave standing on a rock.
>
> c. In the photo you see her, with Dave, standing on a rock.

In which of the above sentences is each of these conclusions correct:

> 1.She is standing on a rock.
>
> 2.Dave is standing on a rock.
>
> 3.They are both standing on a rock.

Answer (score 2):

The comma breaks up the association with "her" and "Dave", **or** it breaks up the association with who is standing on the rock. So:

> a. In the photo you see her with Dave standing on a rock.

Because there are no commas, it implies that both of them are standing on the rock.

> b. In the photo you see her, with Dave standing on a rock.

Because there is that single comma, it is saying that the photo shows her. It also shows Dave standing on a rock. The implication is that she is *not* standing on a rock - but she may be.

> c. In the photo you see her, with Dave, standing on a rock.

This again implies that you see her and Dave together, and they're both standing on a rock.